# Sprite movement style towards one specific point

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, sprite

My sprite image will be moving randomly on the canvas. But after i press on the canvas an object will appear and the sprite image will be moving in a zig zag manner towards it. But i want the sprite to move directly towards the object.

How my sprite image move towards the image that i created after pressing on the canvas:

```
Fish.prototype.chaseFood = function(index) {
    if (this.xPos > foodArray[index].x + foodWidth) {
        this.speedX = -1 * Math.abs(this.speedX);
    } else if (this.xPos < foodArray[index].x) {
        this.speedX = Math.abs(this.speedX);
    }
    if (this.yPos > foodArray[index].y + foodHeight) {
        this.speedY = -1 * Math.abs(this.speedY);
    } else if (this.yPos < foodArray[index].y) {
        this.speedY = Math.abs(this.speedY);
    }
};
```

I know there is a way that is by calculating the slope of the line between the point of the sprite and the object so to allow my sprite image to move towards. But after trying i still couldn't get it. Anybody knows how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You canchange your code to the following for chaseFood

```
Fish.prototype.chaseFood = function (index) {    
    var tx = foodArray[index].x + foodWidth - this.xPos,
        ty = foodArray[index].y + foodHeight - this.yPos,
        dist = Math.sqrt(tx*tx+ty*ty); // better ways to do the distance.

        // 1 can be any speed value to make it go faster or slower
        this.speedX = (tx/dist)*1;
        this.speedY = (ty/dist)*1;
};
```

What this does is gets the distance between the fish and the food, and divides the current x, and y component by the distance making it travel towards the food at a constant speed. Yours was always 1 or -1 so it would bounce back and forth, this method allows it to be a float so it can travel exactly towards the food.

I adapted the code [from an article on my blog](http://www.somethinghitme.com/2013/11/13/snippets-i-always-forget-movement/) which has other helpful recipes for this sort of thing.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/bV4r6/43/)**

Comment: Hi, is it possible to make the sprite image to swim towards it? Instead of the weird moving manner. Means that the mouth of the fish will be facing the food and the body at the back.

Comment: @Bernard yeah it involves some more math. However your question and code didn't really indicate that :P if you want more info on how to do it check out the link in the answer instead of me *giving you teh codez!*